# biblatex: "and" as final delimiter when citing multiple entries

Tags: biblatex, citing

I want to change the style of the final (last) delimiter when citing multiple `.bib` entries with `biblatex`. I know that these can generally be changed by redefining `\multicitedelim`, but I want the citations to be printed like:

> Author 1 (Year), Author 2 (Year) and Author 3 (Year)

instead of

> Author 1 (Year), Author 2 (Year), Author 3 (Year)

I didn't find an option for this in the documentation of `biblatex` - does someone know a solution?

Comment: Note that the development version of `biblatex` (2.7) "has made progress on this issue" (Audrey, one of the developers), though I haven't been able (yet) to test it.

Comment: 2.7, which will be released soon, incorporates this feature into `\textcite` and its variants in all the standard styles. You should upgrade instead of using the duplicate's answer as the solution does not work well with citation hooks and breaks `\tvolcite`.